# Prove $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not countably compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Prove $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not countably compact.

Attempt: Let $\mathcal{C}=\{B_{n}(0)|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ a countable collection of open balls having radius $n$ covering $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose there is a finite subcollection $\mathcal{C}'=\{B_{n_1}(0),...,B_{n_m}(0)\}$ that covers $\mathbb{R}^n$. Choose $m=\text{max}\{n_1,...,n_m\}$. Then $(m,0,...,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is not an element of any $B_{n_i}(0)$ and the countable cover $\mathcal{C}$ has not finite subcover.

Comment: Yes, this works fine. If you don’t want to construct an actual ‘bad’cover, you can argue that $\Bbb R^n$ is Lindelöf (because it is a separable metric space) but not compact, so it cannot be countably compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What would a bad cover mean?

Comment: In this context it would be a countable open cover of $\Bbb R^n$ with no finite subcover, e.g., the one that you constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wonderful.

Here's a different "bad cover": the set of balls with centers having rational coordinates and rational radii.

No finite subcover by the same sort of reasoning you employed: a finite subcover would fit in a ball of finite radius;  but $\mathbb R^n $ is unbounded.